# Cayley-Hamilton Theorem explanation. I'm having trouble interpreting the meaning of $f(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, cayley-hamilton

Using the Theorem from "Linear Algebra" (-Friedberg, Insel, Spence 5th edition).

*(Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, and let $f(t)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $T$, then $f(T)=T_0$, the zero transformation.  That is T "satisfies" its characteristic Equation*

It looks like we're inserting some linear operator as input for the characteristic polynomial.  This notation is used in some proofs in the text that I can find, but I haven't been able to find any explanation.  The $T$ seems to be used interchangeably with the linear operator applied to a matrix fairly often, but I can't make sense of that either.  The $f(T)$ has come up in one of my assigned problems and I can't move forward until I have some understanding of what this means.

Comment: The proof goes on to use the notation $f(T)v=0$ and I don't understand it in that context either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x) = c_nx^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1 x + c_0$ is a polynomial, then $$f(T) = c_nT^n + c_{n-1}T^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1 T + c_0I,$$ where $I$ is the identity operator. Here, $T^n$ is the linear operator $T$ composed with itself $n$-times.
If you fix a basis, then $T$ has an associated matrix $A_T$. In this case $f(A_T)$ makes sense where $A_T^n$ is the $n$-th power of the matrix. Both of these perpectives agree.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  It seems counter-intuitive that matrix exponents behave like real number exponents.  (eigenvalues in this particular case)  I'm thinking through this as I type, so bear with me please.  Am I interpreting this correctly?  $A- tI=0 \implies A^2- t^2I=0$  There seems to be so much going on with Matrix multiplication that this result isn't obvious to me.

Comment: @C-Web $A^2  - t^2 I = (A - tI)(A + tI) = O \cdot (A + tI) = O$

Comment: @C-Web   could you please take $ A  = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
3 & -1 \\ 
5 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)  $  and find $A \cdot A = A^2,$   then find coefficients $m,n$  such that $A^2 + mA + I = 0.$   I would like you to see concrete numbers and matrices.

Comment: @C-Web  that's a start. Please check by calculating $A^2 + 5 A + 11 I$ with just numbers, no variables. If it becomes the zero matrix, you are done, otherwise...

Comment: @WillJagy $f(t)=det(A-tI)=det \begin{pmatrix}3-t & -1 \\ 5 & 2-t \end{pmatrix}=t^2+5t+11$.  $\begin{pmatrix}3 &-1 \\ 5 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}4 &-5 \\ 25 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\\$.  $\begin{pmatrix}4 &-5 \\ 25 & -1 \end{pmatrix}-5\begin{pmatrix}3 &-1 \\ 5 & 2 \end{pmatrix}+11\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4 &-5 \\ 25 & -1 \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}15 &-5 \\ 25 & 10 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}11 &0 \\ 0 & 11 \end{pmatrix}=0$

Comment: @C-Web  good.  As    you found,   it is actually $A^2 - 5A + 11A$ that equals zero.  That is, you made an error in finding the characteristic polynomial.    If I use capital $T$  for the trace of $A$   and $D$  the determinant, the char. poly is  $t^2 - T t + D$  in the 2 by 2 case.

Comment: @WillJagy you lost me.  I'm not sure what "trace" means.  Also, that was a typo on the characteristic polynomial.  I actually had minus on my paper.

Comment: Trace is the sum of the diagonal entries of a square matrix @C-Web.

Comment: @C-Web  I haven't seen your book; given your questions, I suggest deliberately learning the matrix way of writing these things, alongside the class work

Answer (score 2):

If you've seen some rings before there's another perspective you could use. If $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$, and $T$ is a linear operator on $V$, consider the polynomial ring $F[x]$ (which is a ring containing polynomials with coefficients from $F$). Then there is an ring homomorphism $\Phi: F[x] \rightarrow Hom(V,V)$ defined by
$$
f(x) \mapsto f(T).
$$
So what this means is that given an arbitrary polynomial with coefficients from $F$, you can associate to it a linear operator on $V$ by "replacing $x$ with $T$" in the polynomial. So for example if you had a real vector space $V$, then the polynomial $f(x) = 5x^2+3x+1$ would map to
$$
5x^2+3x+1 \mapsto 5T^2+3T+id_V
$$
where here $id_V$ denotes the identity transformation on $V$.

The use of $\Phi$ being a ring homomorphism is that any of the standard algebraic manipulations you can do on elements of $F[x]$ will also work for linear operators in $Hom(V,V)$. And as Zorngo mentionned the powers of $T$ correspond to repeated composition and $T^0 = id_V$.

Also, the notation $f(T)v$ might be clearer now because I've tried to illustrate that $f(T)$ *is itself another linear operator on $V$*, hence $f(T)v$ just means evaluate the linear operator at $v$.  Concretely, if we have the linear operator associated to the polynomial $f(x) = 5x^2+3x+1$ again, then
$$
f(T)v = 5T^2(v)+3T(v)+id_V(v).
$$